# Print preview of an .aspx page I made has its URL appearing three times on the page

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, printing

I made an .aspx page with .VB in the code behind that all it does is pull data from a database onto an asp.net gridview to display a certain high school team's game schedule.
Some parents want to print the schedules, so when they pull up the print preview, the page's URL appears 3 times very predominantly just beneath the header of the page. [Here's a screenshot of the print preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anZFc.png)

Any idea what's going on? I researched and found that it's possible to modify the styles specifically for a printing scenario, but I don't see what CSS code could possible fix this.

EDIT:
I actually figured out that the 3 URLs that appear under the header are the breadcrumbs of the page. I guess my question now is how do I hide them? I already tried adding display: none under a print media query.

Answer (score 0):

Placing this in print css will hide the urls.

```
a[href]:after {
   content:"" !important;
}
```